# maven dependency snapshot version number is different from nexus snapshot version number by 1 second

Tags: maven, maven-3, nexus, nexus3

We are using Maven as build manager and Nexus as our artifact repository.
From time to time we are having this dependency problem and Maven is not able to find the artifact in Nexus by a slight difference in the snapshot version number. In this case, the difference seems to be 1 second.

Currently, a build is failing, maven is looking for

> SOME_ARTIFACT-0.0.1-20181217.1153**18**-337.jar

but on the Nexus we have

> SOME_ARTIFACT-0.0.1-20181217.1153**17**-337.jar

This is not happening all the time, but from time to time I see this problem, and in order to solve this I need to redeploy SOME_ARTIFACT before building the application that depends on SOME_ARTIFACT.

Do you have any idea why this is happening? I know I can use release versions and totally avoid this snapshot issue but this SOME_ARTIFACT is under constant update and development, so I don't wanna keep releasing, plus, what I want is to figure out the reason behind this problem not to basically avoid it.

- Maven version: 3.5.0
- NEXUS version: OSS 3.12.1-01

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for providing the Maven version. Likely you are being impacted by https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-6240. Update Maven (or downgrade to 3.3.9) and that should help.